# Simplest LAMP incremental backup solution?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, backup, lamp, database-backups

I have a VPS which has daily offsite backups of the entire system, so that is in order!

However this server is running a community wiki-site powered by the LAMP stack on an Ubuntu server and we wish to have a local, more frequent backup solution should anything bad happen.

I have tried researching the topic and it seems there are an infinite amount of possibilities, so I come here open to suggestions as to what we could do - hopefully a solution that is as simple as possible yet still effective.

From my research so far, a rsync shell-script & cron could be a potential solution. As could rsnapshot. But I am quite lost with the different options and would very much appreciate a potential solution to our backup-needs. We do want incremental backups if possible, so as to avoid extra costs on our VPS.

Comment: ubuntu has Déjà Dup built in which I think should work perfectly fine for this job

Comment: Sadly I think Déjà Dup is not of much use, as the server is headless and it seems Déjà Dup does not have a command line version.

Comment: Still looking for a solution!